# Spring XML cannot find my Spring Java Configuration Class

Tags: java, spring, maven

So I have been using the 3.2.0.RELEASE Spring XML configurations for most of my beans but now I am faced with a unique situation where the Getters and Setters can't be used (bad legacy code - can't get around it).

As such, I want to use Spring @Configuration class and the XML to workaround this problem.

However, I am getting "Class Not Found" exception when it tries to read my @Configuration Class.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: v1.inventory.item.myJavaConfig

My XML file which is failing looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="v1.inventory.item.myJavaConfig"/>
</beans>
```

My @Configuration class looks like this:

```
package v1.inventory.item;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:v1/inventory/item/baseItemConfigs.xml")
public class myJavaConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("parentItem")
    Item baseItem;

    @Bean
    public Item realItem(){
        Item modifiedBean = baseItem;

        modifiedBean.setManufacturer("Fake Setter for Manufacturer");
        modifiedBean.setDesigner("Fake Setter for Designer");

        return modifiedBean;
    }
}
```

I need this to be read by the ApplicationContext so I need to make sure these beans can be found. Is this a bug with Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE? Or my code?

For the record, I am pulling in the @Configuration last (parentItem is scanned first in XML).

Comment: Why do you have nested `<beans>` tag in your xml config file? Is that even valid xml file?

Comment: I copied and pasted from the documentation. And yes everything compiles and Spring doesn't complain about a parsing issue. I'll try removing it so see if I get a different error though.

Comment: After removing the extra <beans> tag, it is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue here.

It seems that maven/spring (not sure which) wasn't looking in my "resource" directory for the file. Only my "java" directory. When I moved my file into the "java" directory, Spring found the file just fine.

The tests which were passing in JUnit now pass using the Maven compiler (which was throwing the above error during the test phase)